# Popup message cannot display new update records from php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've made a popup message with auto-refresh function, so every few minutes the popup will appear to display the records. And it worked.

The following is the JavaScript code that auto refreshes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#rtnotice').load('plugins/notice/n_notice_invoice.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000)
});
```

code of n_notice_invoice.php

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#noticearea").hide();
        });
    });
    </script>

<?php
    try{
    require_once "../../config/c_config.php";
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    $timestamp = $_REQUEST['term'];
    $sqlck = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_notice_alert) as ttlinv FROM str_notice_alert WHERE date_alert > '$timestamp'");
    $sqlck->execute();
    $resck = $sqlck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($resck['ttlinv'] == '0')
    {}else{
    ?>
    <div id="noticearea">
    <div id="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="header">
                    <div id="circle" align="center"><h1><?php echo $resck['ttlinv'];?></h1></div><div class="titlenotice"><h1>NOTICE ALERT<?php echo $timestamp; ?></h1></div>
                    <div class="break"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="copy">
                    <p>
                    <table width="100%" class="gridtable">
                    <tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Location</th><th>Date</th></tr>
    <?php 
    $sqll = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM str_notice_alert");
    $sqll->execute();
    while($resl = $sqll->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    ?>
    <tr><td align="center"><?php echo $resl['id_notice_alert']; ?></td><td><?php echo $resl['alert_name']; ?></td><td align="center"><?php echo $resl['alert_status']; ?></td><td align="center"><?php echo $resl['alert_location']; ?></td><td><?php echo $resl['date_alert']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="cf footer">
                    <button id="hide" class="btn">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div></div>
    <?php 

    $sqltrunc = $db->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE str_notice_alert");
    $sqltrunc->execute();

    }$db = null;}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection Error " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

After a popup message is displayed, it will display the file n_notice_invoice.php existing records and also delete the records via queries available. In any appearances. But the question is, why the records are not updated / changed. uUnless I refresh the file directly n_notice_invoice.php, and then auto-refresh displays the most recent data.

Comment: Can you show the n_notice_invoice.php page?

Comment: @lelio faieta : I have show above, thanks

Comment: Edited my answer to show you what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timestamp = $_REQUEST['term'];
```

should be updated each time you call the page. You should load the page with Ajax passing $timestamp as a parameter instead of just loading it.

To get what you need can I suggest you to use long polling? PHP long polling or even better with node.js. For php for example the "server" page:

```
$timeStart = time();
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','polldb');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

// select where item is new
if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
}else{
    // get current database time
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT now() as now'));
    $timestamp = $row['now'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE timestamp > '$timestamp'";

$newData = false;
$notifications = array();

// loop while there is no new data and is running for less than 20 seconds
while(!$newData && (time()-$timeStart)<20){

    // check for new data
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $notifications[] = $row;
        $newData = true;
    }
    // let the server rest for a while
    usleep ( 500000 );
}

// get current database time
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT now() as now'));
$timestamp = $row['now'];
mysqli_close($con);

// output
$data = array('notifications'=>$notifications,'timestamp'=>$timestamp);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

and the client:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    pullNotification();
});

function pullNotification(timestamp){
    var data = {};
    if(typeof timestamp!='undefined')
        data.timestamp = timestamp;

    $.post('longpoll.php',data,function(msg){

        var newData = '';
        for(i in msg.notifications){
            newData+=msg.notifications[i].message+'\n';
        }
        if(newData!='')
            alert(newData);
        pullNotification(msg.timestamp);
    },'json');
}
</script>
```

This will check for database updates and will pop them up. Every 20 seconds it will renew the request. Obviously you have to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believie your issue comes from cached request (in Browser on in ajax itself)
please try to disable ajax caching :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
       $.ajax({
        url: "plugins/notice/n_notice_invoice.php",
        cache: false
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('#rtnotice').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 5000)
});
```

Comment: Actually he is not doing an ajax call at all but just simulating it.